# php -> foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

I want to create a form, which is basically a text area which has e-mail addresses on new lines:

For example;

```
<textarea>
emailone@domain.com,
emailone@domain.com,
emailone@domain.com,
emailone@domain.com,
emailone@domain.com,
emailone@domain.com,
emailone@domain.com,
emailone@domain.com,
emailone@domain.com
</textarea>
```

I then want this form to submit to a php page, which will split the e-mail addresses and put them into a loop, so I could paste a list of 300 e-mails into a text area, in that format, and then submit the form and it would do a foreach loop for EACH individual e-mail (e-mail them).

Could somebody please explain how I would split the e-mail addresses up individually and then process them into a loop?

Thanks a bunch

Comment: Sounds like a recipe for spam, especially if the form is not secured properly...that is if that isn't what the original intention was.

Comment: It is a form I will be using myself to send e-mails to a list of subscribers I have, save me putting them into a database and running it from there, make things easier and just paste them all into a text area and submit it. It won't be used by anyone else, just an administrative tool to make things easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the email addresses are comma separated, use

```
$addresses = explode(',', $textareaValue);
foreach ($addresses as $address) {
    $address = trim($address); // Remove any extra whitespace
}
```

If you want to split the addresses on a number of different characters (comma, newline, space, etc) use `preg_split` in place of `explode`

```
$addresses = preg_split('/[\s,]+/', $textareaValue);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, will give it a go today!

Answer (score 1):

To get them into an array you can use PHP's [explode](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function which splits a string up based on a string delimiter:

```
$email_addresses = explode(",\n", $email_address_string);
foreach ($email_addresses as $email_address) {
    // Process $email_address
}
```